# Maximum period of a vertically spinning ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

**Problem:** A point mass with mass $m$, tethered by a string of length $R$, is in unforced circular motion in a gravitational field with strength $g$. 
The plane of motion is parallel to the gravitational field lines.
The period of motion is $T$.
What is the largest possible $T$?
(ignore friction and any heat loss)

This a problem that I made up, but I'm sure it has been posed and answered before. I cannot find any reference. **What I want to know is if my assumption for solving this problem is correct.**

**Assumption:** For the path to be circular, the string must be under tension.
Minimum tension is when the mass is at the top of the loop.
Maximum period corresponds to zero tension at this point.

**Added:**
Reason for the assumption:
The radial acceleration $a=v^2/R$ is toward the center. $g$ is  downward. 
The lower half of the circle is a pendulum and the path is circular.
In the upper half of the circle, the tension is $m(v^2/R - g \sin(\theta))$,
where $\theta$ is angular displacement measured counterclockwise from positive x-axis.
Minimum tension is reached at $\theta=\pi/2$. Since tension must be grater or equal to zero,
$v^2 \ge g R$. Maximum period corresponds to lowest tangential speed, $v^2=gR$.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start out right - the tension is zero at the top, and that gives you the velocity at the top of the arc. The velocity at the bottom is right too. However, I don't think you can simply take the average velocity... instead you need to write down the integral equation.

At a given angle $\theta$, you have height $h$ and velocity $v$. From conservation of energy we known

$$\frac12 m v^2 + m g h = 2mgR + \frac12 m v_0^2 = \frac52 mgR$$

Now we can write $h$ in terms of $\theta$:

$$h = R(1+\cos\theta)$$

We can do the same thing for $v$:

$$v = R\dot\theta$$

Together, these make a differential equation:

$$\begin{align}v^2 &= 5gR - 2gh\\
\left(\dot\theta R\right)^2 &=5gR - 2gR(1+\cos\theta)\\
&=gR(3-2\cos\theta)\end{align}$$

A bit of rearranging gives

$$dt = \sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{3-2\cos\theta}}$$

This is a hard thing to integrate; so we turn to Wolfram Alpha, which tells us we should have paid more attention when we learnt about elliptical integrals... When the right hand side is integrated from $0$ to $\pi$, the left hand side gives us half the period:

$$T = 2\sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}\left(2K(-4)\right) \\
\require{AMScd}\bbox[border:2px solid red]{T= 4.038 \sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}}$$

where K is the elliptical integral of the first kind.

Because I don't trust my own math skills, I did the integration numerically - and am happy to say I got basically the same answer:

[image]

As you can see, the line crosses the $2\pi$ line at just a touch over $4\sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}$ - this is consistent with the value 4.038 that I got from Wolfram Alpha. This is slightly longer than the value you calculated (which comes to 3.703), which is not surprising: even if you assume a linear change in velocity, you have to take account of the time spent at each velocity - your expression doesn't do that...

Comment: +1 Thank you. As Gert said it is too late to think now. I'll read your answer tomorrow,. But it looks good :)

Comment: "too late" depends on your time zone. Gert is in the UK... so yes it was very late there.

Comment: @Floris: I understood that OP's 'average' was wrong and that some expression for $v (or \omega) = f(t)$ had to be developed to calculate $T$. I couldn't see the right way though. Thanks for solving that.

Comment: @Floris Thanks again, I've had time to read your solution in detail. Shouldn't the integral be taken from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$? The reason I say that is that motion is not symmetric with respect to the horizontal axis, but it is symmetric with respect to the vertical axis. If I do that, numerical integration gives me $5.01024 \sqrt{R/g}$.

Comment: You would be right - but I had put $\theta=0$ at the top... serves me right for not drawing a diagram. That's why you have the $h=R(1+\cos\theta)$ expression - if I had put $theta=0$ at 3 o'clock, I would have needed a $\sin\theta$ term.

Comment: Curious about the fly-by downvote...

Comment: This may have something to do with it: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7570/incosistent-policy-on-homework-questions.

Comment: Well yes - the question I answered isn't the question you morphed it into... Which is a shame because I didn't think that was a bad question to begin with.

Comment: I agree. I edited the question only after the question was put on hold and closed. I was quite happy with the question as it was and your answer. For what is worth, you have my apology for the mess and thanks for an excellent answer. Please let me know if you want me to "unaccept" your answer.

Comment: Don't worry - stuff happens...